# how to compress apk size in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a simple test game in unity3d using c#, the size of the apk of my game is 70 MB.I have reduced the resolution of each and ever sprites, but its still 58 MB, how do i compress the game so that the apk file is of the least possible size.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from following this short guide by [Unity themselves](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html), there are a couple things to keep in mind:

1. Files which are not used or dependent on are removed by Unity when building.
2. Textures, music and videos take up most of the size.  Sound files should ideally be `.mp3` format (otherwise `.wav` for very short clips).

I would recommend you go through the link above and properly analyse `Editor.log` as it provides valuable information to trim the build size.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose to set the Device filter to Arm7. This will exclude certain devices, but I believe the number is quite small and it does minimize the apk size a bit. (This is located in Player Setting -> Other Settings -> Device Filter). You could try a build and see how much it would reduce it by and decide whether it was worth it.

Some Info on device filter: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/971648/device-filter-to-arm-7-only.html

Additionally, if you look in your editor build file you can find information on what is taking up the majority of space in your build (it is a long log so you'll have to search for the right parts). There should be a part in it after you do a build that will list how much space things are taking up. It will be followed by a list of the assets from largest to smallest so you can identify particular assets that may be too large.

E.g.

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      81.1 mb    92.0% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    17.1 kb    0.0% 
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Shaders       90.0 kb    0.1% 
Other Assets  549.9 kb   0.6% 
Levels        338.3 kb   0.4% 
Scripts       993.0 kb   1.1% 
Included DLLs 5.1 mb     5.8% 
File headers  33.1 kb    0.0% 
Complete size 88.2 mb    100.0%
```

How to find editor file: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Answer (score 1):

One most effective and important change for reduce image size is

## Set your image size square and

## Set unity suggested pixels.(32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192)

If your image size is 567x890 pixels  then set this image in a 1024x1024 pixels background transparent blank image and save it as a png file.

Then in unity inspector set this image as a sprite and slice it by sprite editor.
This process will make your image size reduce minimum 20%.

**Example image and changes given below.**

**Before:** resolution 567x890 pixel, size 1.9MB

**After:** resolution 1024x1024 pixel, size 1.3MB

**Result:** size 0.6MB reduced, almost 32%.

Image file Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zkzr6JdNYlaHhqcDVUSk9KNjA/view

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to set texture / sprite compression format.

Check this website:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html

Most texture compression format needs image in power of 2 resolution (128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048). Resolutions 4096 and 8192 may not work on some android devices.

For example texture with no alpha in 1024x1024 resolution using RGB ETC2 compressions takes about 0,5MB in memory. Image 1280x800 with compression format RGB 16bit takes 2MB.